# how to handle unbalanced data for multilabel classification using CNN in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, multilabel-classification, imbalanced-data

My dataset shape is `(91149, 12)`

I used CNN to train my classifier in text classification tasks

I found Training Accuracy: `0.5923` and Testing Accuracy: `0.5780`

My Class has 9 labels as below:

```
df['thematique'].value_counts()
Corporate                   42399
Economie collaborative      13272
Innovation                  11360
Filiale                      5990
Richesses Humaines           4445
Relation sociétaire          4363
Communication                4141
Produits et services         2594
Sites Internet et applis     2585
```

The model structure:

```
model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix],   input_length=maxlen   ,   trainable=False)
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Conv1D(128, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics= ['categorical_accuracy'])
```

My data for multilabel classification is imbalanced. I need to handle imbalanced data for multipabel classification using CNN in Keras.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you need to handle the imbalance issue using in particular Keras per se, rather than using some intuition. One simple way to do so is to use the same amount of data per each class. Of course, that causes another problem, which is that you filter a lot of samples. But still is a thing that you can check. Of course, when you have imbalance data it is not a very good idea to just calculate the classification performance since it does so well how each class performs.

You should further, calculate the confusion matrix, in order to visualize how well each class performs individually. A more detailed approach to imbalanced data issues could be found in this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/methods-for-dealing-with-imbalanced-data-5b761be45a18) and in [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/methods-for-dealing-with-imbalanced-data-5b761be45a18).

The most important is to use the right tools to evaluate the performance of your classification, and also handle the input data as proposed in the links I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy could be misleading as a metric for your problem, with high class imbalance, I would use the **F1** score.

As for the loss, you could use the [**focal loss**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf) it is an variant of the **categorical cross-entropy** that focuses on the **least represented** classes. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/umbertogriffo/focal-loss-keras/blob/master/losses.py), in my experience, it helps a lot with little classes on NLP classification tasks.